# Получить при открытии страницы значение input

Tags: php, javascript, curl

Как при открытии страницы получить значение `input` с другого сайта?
При открытии страницы подгружаю файл get.php который берет значение input с другого сайта. JS вывожу полученное значение, но ничего не выводит. Где я ошибся?

Файл get.php

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("https://ecom.akbars.ru/cgi-bin/cgi_link?TERMINAL=93200011");
preg_match('/<input type="hidden" value="(.*)" id="Form_id" name="FORM_ID"/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

JavaScript для вывода результатов:

```
<?php include 'get.php'; ?>

<script>
$.get('get.php', {}, function(data){
    alert('значение');
alert(data);});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас регулярка неправильная. Вот так попробуйте:

```
/<input type="hidden" class="txt" id="Form_id" name="FORM_ID"\svalue="(.*)"/im
```

По поводу обрезанной строки, попробовал как у вас через file_get_contents, действительно другую строку подставляет. Попробовал с помощью curl - помогло, возвращает нормальную строку

```
$url = 'https://ecom.akbars.ru/cgi-bin/cgi_link?TERMINAL=93200011';

function get_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.17) Gecko/2009122116 Firefox/3.0.17");
    $headers = array
    (
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Charset: windows-1251, utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "google.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // выполняем запрос curl
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$data = get_url($url);
```

Подозреваю что дело в заголовках, но проверять не стал в каких именно.

Comment: а не подскажите что это /im значит?

Comment: подскажу. i - регистро-независимый поиск. а m - мультистроковый поиск. вообще можете в [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) почитать

Comment: а еще вопрос, все выводит- просто супер, но на конце пишет два знака == и если глянуть на сайт где form_id то там больше символов чем мне выдает

Comment: выводит у меня от так yiFK+gbvRH3IMmBtEV7n+m2ZqbU0vwdKNyiTeohQrJFcAgtmeZ+swmcyr+r0MT0mGpQM7wm8CNUI58CJj044sUzDYQcIpzvI+LUfKZTWKQxUe1EUHQ==

Comment: а на сайте другом вот так 9FG4aApmXP8iuS48rvO41GvWvSraz+7MMJMxBxue2VXZGgNvpeaKTho0ZTE5411NSAo0vkaBoKqTeuuBcLY4ADrf4pNuPAMPQZrzyd6GudIqXq4dgZzUdQEoGU0nfqW2wZ0BZQ2QC4IPcv117j+8qCVF8QUJst0+9LWPVABBj+kONqwr/+mMqEx2ctqAaekvsmPb3febAa2KI5swSzKp9ehsDLb6p0tqUQUDNkuk42IfkFBoQd6MOARRlW0X25EyCs8fawj90KkfmYUhCpeKkVBy1iqphRiF5/tC5MmFWLEARxCKY0pSizFvZRq2DXplZS0Qc09pgD+VVSAH/dQ1cMv+dxUuLnwNE6lHB0lBuPfXbOPMlW872o+udyP2u+i0lRIGuaYiWOtE7f5TmXPCLxEsqcDKAOx1aeytJH3mMPsXIx9Qli1dYyJXEgqSZ5OxFcyxS46h

Comment: Не понятно что конктретно не так, приведите пример строки какая должна быть и какую выводит.

Comment: должна быть такая 9FG4aApmXP8iuS48rvO41GvWvSraz+7MMJMxBxue2VXZGgNvpeaKTho0ZTE5‌​411NSAo0vkaBoKqTeuuB‌​cLY4ADrf4pNuPAMPQZrz‌​yd6GudIqXq4dgZzUdQEo‌​GU0nfqW2wZ0BZQ2QC4IP‌​cv117j+8qCVF8QUJst0+‌​9LWPVABBj+kONqwr/+mM‌​qEx2ctqAaekvsmPb3feb‌​Aa2KI5swSzKp9ehsDLb6‌​p0tqUQUDNkuk42IfkFBo‌​Qd6MOARRlW0X25EyCs8f‌​awj90KkfmYUhCpeKkVBy‌​1iqphRiF5/tC5MmFWLEA‌​RxCKY0pSizFvZRq2DXpl‌​ZS0Qc09pgD+VVSAH/dQ1‌​cMv+dxUuLnwNE6lHB0lB‌​uPfXbOPMlW872o+udyP2‌​u+i0lRIGuaYiWOtE7f5T‌​mXPCLxEsqcDKAOx1aeyt‌​JH3mMPsXIx9Qli1dYyJX‌​EgqSZ5OxFcyxS46h

Comment: а выводит такую  9FG4aApmXP8iuS48rvO41GvWvSraz+7MMJMxBxue2VXZGgNvpeaKTho0ZTE5‌​‌​411NSAo0vkaBoKqTeu‌​uB‌​cLY4ADrf4pNuPAMP‌​QZrz‌​yd6GudIqXq4dgZ‌​zUdQEo‌​GU0nfqW2wZ0B‌​ZQ2QC4IP‌​cv117j+8qC‌​VF8QUJst0+‌​9LWPVABB‌​j+kONqwr==

Comment: а в `$matches[1]` у вас исходная строка или обрезанная ?

Comment: обрезанная тоже

Comment: а в переменной $str тоже обрезанная ?

Comment: да тоже выводит инпут с value обрезанным

Comment: вот сайт откуда беру form_id https://ecom.akbars.ru/cgi-bin/cgi_link?TERMINAL=93200011

Comment: Ну значит такая строка генерируется, когда вы `file_get_contents` делаете. я не знаю каким образом она формируется.

Comment: а почему он так обрезать может?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: не понял ничего)

Comment: а есть какой другой способ вытащить это значение?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще есть интересная, но старая библиотека PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser для парсинга html и работы с ним по типу jquery, весьма удобно. Но вообще попробуйте попросить api у ресурса который хотите парсить) а то парсить это ресурсоёмко и если есть шанс этого избежать, то почему бы не попробовать?) 
[Ссылка на статейку о данной библиотеке](http://xdan.ru/uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html)